# Will 70% isopropyl alcohol deactivate i.e. kill COVID-19?

Tags: infection, disease-transmission, microbiology

Today the CDC released an [official list](https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2020-03/documents/sars-cov-2-list_03-03-2020.pdf) of what kills the COVID-19 virus but the list does not mention 70% isopropyl alcohol.

This is a fairly basic disinfectant and it seems it should have been on the list assuming it kills the virus and that is why I am asking. Thank you

Comment: Can you please add a link to the CDC list and quote it in your question? Remember, this question might be seen years from now when finding that list could be impossible.

Comment: @Carey Gregory     https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2020-03/documents/sars-cov-2-list_03-03-2020.pdf

Comment: I've done it for you this time, but in the future when you add information to a question, please edit the question and add it there, not in comments.

Comment: Just a heads-up... COVID-19 is the disease caused by the new coronavirus. The virus is called SARS-CoV-2. - https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/technical-guidance/naming-the-coronavirus-disease-(covid-2019)-and-the-virus-that-causes-it

Comment: @Carey Gregory , will do . Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does.

According to the CDC, [this](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/community/home/cleaning-disinfection.html) is how surfaces should be disinfected:

> ### Surfaces
>
> - Wear disposable gloves when cleaning and disinfecting surfaces. Gloves should be discarded after each cleaning. If reusable gloves are
>     used, those gloves should be dedicated for cleaning and disinfection
>     of surfaces for COVID-19 and should not be used for other purposes.
>     Consult the manufacturer’s instructions for cleaning and disinfection
>     products used. Clean hands immediately after gloves are removed.
> - If surfaces are dirty, they should be cleaned using a detergent or soap and water prior to disinfection.
> - For disinfection, diluted household bleach solutions, **alcohol solutions with at least 70% alcohol**, and most common EPA-registered
>     household disinfectants should be effective.
>
>   - Diluted household bleach solutions can be used if appropriate for the surface. Follow manufacturer’s instructions for application
>       and proper ventilation. Check to ensure the product is not past its
>       expiration date. Never mix household bleach with ammonia or any other
>       cleanser. Unexpired household bleach will be effective against
>       coronaviruses when properly diluted.
>
>     - Prepare a bleach solution by mixing:
>
>       - 5 tablespoons (1/3rd cup) bleach per gallon of water or
>       - 4 teaspoons bleach per quart of water
>   - A list of products with EPA-approved emerging viral pathogens claims, maintained by the American Chemistry Council Center for
>       Biocide Chemistries (CBC), is available at:
>       https://www.americanchemistry.com/Novel-Coronavirus-Fighting-Products-List.pdf.
>       Products with EPA-approved emerging viral pathogens claims are
>       expected to be effective against COVID-19 based on data for harder to
>       kill viruses. Follow the manufacturer’s instructions for all cleaning
>       and disinfection products (e.g., concentration, application method and
>       contact time, etc.).
> - For soft (porous) surfaces such as carpeted floor, rugs, and drapes, remove visible contamination if present and clean with
>     appropriate cleaners indicated for use on these surfaces. After
>     cleaning: Launder items as appropriate in accordance with the
>     manufacturer’s instructions. If possible, launder items using the
>     warmest appropriate water setting for the items and dry items
>     completely, or Use products with the EPA-approved emerging viral
>     pathogens claims (examples at this linkpdf iconexternal icon) that are
>     suitable for porous surfaces.

Answer (score 3):

The List does mention Isopropyl Alcohol. It's sixth on the list, and it's listed by its other name--Isopropanol.

Isopropanol=Isopropyl Alcohol. Just like Ethanol=Ethyl Alcohol.